# AS2 to AS3 conversion

Tags: flash

```
// This is AS2 Coding

this.createEmptyMovieClip("some_mc", 1);
some_mc.loadVariables("external.txt");
some_mc.onEnterFrame = function() {
    if (this.done == "yes") {
        // the variables have finished loading
        trace("**\nfinished loading\n**\nthe variables are:");
        trace(this.fName); // outputs nuno 
        trace(this.lName); // outputs mira 
        trace(this.age); // outputs 24 
        // delete the method to end the loop
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    }  else  { 
        // not loaded yet
        trace("**\nstill loading\n**");
    }
};

//I want AS3 Coding

//in the text file external.txt data:

&fName=nuno& 
&lName=mira& 
&age=24&
```

Answer (score 0):

So what are the chances that this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909409/how-to-read-text-file-external-txt-in-as3 was also submitted by you?
Double question and profile, sneaky...
You should close one of them.

And in any case the code you have there is not exactly best practice, and neither is the format in the text file.
I would suggest using xml instead, but in the other question you seem to insist on using the near standard text format (normally it would be **fName=nuno&lName=mira&age=24**).

Anyway, to do it you first need to load in the text with an [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary), the example should give you all you need.

Then you need to parse the text, I would suggest [Regex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/RegExp.html#includeExamplesSummary), the example should give you most of what you need. You should be able to parse it with **/&(.+)=(.+)&/g** (check [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000112.html) on capturing substrings), where the first substring is the name and the second the value.

Then you can finally run through the arrays you end up with and put everything into a [Dictionary](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) so you can access the values by name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply you have to use URLLoader,URLRequest & URLVariables class in as3, see my example code in below.

    private var _vars:URLVariables;
    private Var _urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("external.txt"));
    _urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onURLLoaderCompleteHandler);
    private function onURLLoaderCompleteHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
    _vars = new URLVariables(loader.data);
       some_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameRunning);
    }

    private function onFrameRunning(e:Event):void
    {
        if(_vars != null)
         {
             trace("fname :"_vars.fname);
             trace("lname :"_vars.lname);
             trace("age :"_vars.age);
         }
    }

//in the text file external.txt data:
fname=nuno&lname=mira&age=24
```